# How to resolve a compile error in c++ code?

Tags: c++, class, oop

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
  void reverseWords(string& s)
  {
    cout << s;
  }
};

int main()
{
  string c;
  // c= (char *) malloc(100*sizeof(char ));
  c = "sahil solanki";
  Solution::reverseWords(&c);
}
```

When I compile this program it's giving me errors so how to remove errors. I am new to object oriented programming.

Comment: In case anyone else was wondering `error: no matching function for call to 'Solution::reverseWords(std::string*)'`

Comment: The quickest/easiest fix in this case is to make reverseWords static.

Comment: Removing errors in object oriented programming works same as in procdeual programming. Read the error text, get what it means and fix it. thats all.

Answer (score 4):

```
Solution::reverseWords(&c);
```

This is looking for a *static* (or "class") function `reverseWords()`, which does not exist. (Hence the error message "no matching function".) I will not explain what a class function is, as it's beyond the scope of a simple SO answer (and most likely not what you are looking for at this point anyway).

To call a `Solution` function, you need an *object* (or *instance*, thanks Yann4) of that type:

```
Solution sol;         // construct a Solution object named sol
sol.reverseWords(c);  // tell the sol object to reverseWords()
```

The general idea of "object orientation" is that `class Solution` defines *both* the data *and* the functions operating on that data (as opposed to C, where data is defined usually in a `struct`, and then several independently-defined functions operate on that data).

Note that you do not need `&c` in the call to `reverseWords()`; that would be taking the *address* of `c`, which is not required:

```
void reverseWords( string & s );
```

This is a function that takes a string *reference*. I.e., you call it with a string *object* as argument. The "address taking" you might be familiar with from C, allowing to modify the argument, happens automatically due to the argument type being *reference of*. If you don't want the argument to be modifyable, you either declare a `const` reference...

```
void reverseWords( string const & s );
```

...or an object (which, however, creates a *copy* of the argument on the stack instead):

```
void reverseWords( string s );
```

Either way, you *call* the function as `sol.reverseWords(c)`, i.e. without `&` operator.

And, of course, as juanchopanza pointed out, if you *use* `std::string`, you have to `#include <string>`.

---

Three losely related notes:

- "naked" pointers (the kind that results from `&c` or `malloc()`) are seldom, if ever, necessary in modern C++. Use references where you can, and [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) where you must.
- `using namespace std;` is OK in small test programs. In larger code bases, and especially header files, explicit namespace qualification (e.g. `std::string`) is better.
- while C++ supports object orientation, it is truly a multi-paradigm language; don't get lured into thinking that "everything should be an object".

Comment: In case OP hasn't heard of the term "object" like that, it's also sometimes called an "instance"

Comment: OP should also `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create an object of class `Solution` and then call your function using that object.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
  void reverseWords(string s)
  {
    cout << s;
  }
};

int main()
{
  string c;
  // c= (char *) malloc(100*sizeof(char ));
  c = "sahil solanki";
  Solution s;
  s.reverseWords(c);
}
```

**edit:**

You can call your function without creating an object if you make your function `static`.
Replace

```
void reverseWords(string s)
```

with

```
static void reverseWords(string s)
```